# Dimensions Column of Windows Explorer is Blank

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, images, metadata, dimensions

I could swear that Windows (XP) used to show the width and height of images in Explorer if I toggle the *Dimensions* column, but now it is showing nothing (see screenshot below).

I am working with folders containing many images, so I need to see be able to instantly see the dimensions of pictures as well as sort them.

Am I crazy or did this used to work? What’s wrong and how do I fix it?

[image: Screenshot of Explorer with a blank Dimensions column]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your pain `◑‿◑` (hey, others might find their way here).

One thing to check is the [perceived type](http://theeldergeek.com/image_dimensions_missing.htm) for images. For example, to ensure that the type for JPEGs is correct, check the registry for the following (or modify if necessary):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg]
"PerceivedType"="image"
```

However this may not work (it didn’t for me) and the setting may already be correct.

Another, easier, faster, simpler, and safer way to fix this issue (which worked for me) is to simply re-register Windows built-in image-handling shell-extension (should work in Windows 7 as well):

```
regsvr32 shimgvw.dll
```

You’ll need to restart Explorer for it to take effect (reboot, log out and in, or kill Explorer and run it).

Done:

[image: Screenshot of Explorer with the Dimensions column populated]

As to *why* it wasn’t working, I don’t know. Obviously some setting (likely in the registry) had been changed (e.g., a program associated various image types). It may also have been changed by disabling a file-handler or some such. If I get some time to do some experiments, I’ll try to determine the exact setting, but fixing it is as simple as running the above command (and restarting Explorer).

Comment: It should work for other versions of Windows like Vista and 7 as well.