# Win10 Explorer Dimension Column Blank

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, media, dimensions, column

Just noticed that my explorer in Windows 10 doesn't show the dimensions of my images or videos anymore.

Explorer Example:
[image: Explorer Example]

I remember having the Width, Height and Dimension columns working before but after a reinstall of windows 10 it seems to have stopped working.
I did try the tips on this 9 year old thread
[Dimensions Column of Windows Explorer is Blank](https://superuser.com/questions/614304/dimensions-column-of-windows-explorer-is-blank)

The regsvr32 command gives this error:
[image: The regsvr32 command gives this error]

Some programs that i use that could potentially mix with these inside the registry are Icaros, MediaInfo and PotPlayer as default media player. I have tried to uninstall all 3 but that didn't work.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone else wondering about this, the Frame Height and Frame Width is the columns that work.

[image: Columns]

Answer (score 1):

The Dimensions column only works for images.

Your Explorer image shows that you're viewing MP4 video files, for which
Dimensions does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

The Dimensions column is still working Windows 10 and 11 for the file types that apply (images but not sound, not videos).

Make sure after your reinstall that you are fully up to date, including both regular and optional updates.

Windows 10 Optional Updates have in past included .NET Framework updates and these very likely need to be done.

Then run DISM / SFC

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. 
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup 
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth 
(4) SFC /SCANNOW 
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

[image: Windows 10 Dimension Column]